# Cannot get specific attribute from xml

Tags: php, xml

I've been reading tutorials for the past hour, following them to a T and still have not been able to get this code to work. All i want to do is get the attribute from my xml.

xml:

```
<xml>
<topic input='test' output="test"/>
</xml>
```

php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
$uinput = strtolower($_GET['input']);
foreach($xml->topic as $topic)
{
    foreach($topic->attributes() as $attr)
    {
        echo $attr['output'];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your xml pls show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second foreach if accessing by key. Try this

```
foreach($xml->topic as $topic)
{
  print $topic->attributes()['input'];
}
```

Comment: That did it... I don't understand why LITERALLY every tutorial I read regarding this said the second foreach loop is necessary.